# Flask FileStorage object to File Object

Tags: python, flask, io

I have made an api through `flask` which submit a file and after receiving it on the back end , I want to further upload this to an unknown server using python `requests` module

The server accepts the file if I do this like -

```
requests.post(urlToUnknownServer,files={'file':open('pathToFile')})
```

Now my requirement is to get the file param uploaded through flask.
In flask I get the file as `FileStorage` object. I don't want to save this on my server, instead directly wants it to upload further.
So basically I want to convert that `FileStorage` object to return type of `open()` function which is `file`(please correct me here if I am wrong)

I had tried it using -

```
obj=file(request.files['fileName'].read().encode('string-escape'))
requests.post(urlToUnknownServer,files={'file':obj})
```

This doesn't work. Can it be possible to do that without saving file on my server.

Comment: Hi Sagar, I am going through the same issue. Did you find solution? I want to extract the file from file storagr object.

Comment: @Sagar I am also stack with this issue. I am using postman to send file to flask api. then my flask api send file to 3rd party api. for example **r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files={'file': file.read()})** . I am getting issue at 3rd party api. 3rd party api says invalid image extension...I am sending same image direct to 3rd party api using postman then it works...Help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can use read() without encoding it. such as this:

```
obj=request.files['fileName'].read()
requests.post(urlToUnknownServer,files={'file':obj})
```

Comment: I am using postman to send file to flask api. then my flask api send file to 3rd party api. for example **r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files={'file': file.read()})** . I am getting issue at 3rd party api. 3rd party api says invalid image extension...I am sending same image direct to 3rd party api using postman then it works...Help me.

Comment: @NaisargParmar Are you sending all the headers through flask that is being sent by postman ?

Comment: @sagar Thankx for reply..I am sending this request to 3rd party api **r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files={'file': (file.filename, file.read(), file.content_type)})**. Now with this post request, at-least I am able to create file to their server..but the content of the file is empty. It means **file.read()** is not working perfectly

Comment: @NaisargParmar any luck with empty file?

Comment: @PreritMohan I did little hack. 1. I save file in backend. 2. Read that file. 3. Attached that file to 3rd party api. 4. Delete file in backend.  # Save File
 file = request.files['file']
 file.save(secure_filename(file.filename))
# Send File to 3rd party API
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files={'file': (file.filename, open(file.filename, 'rb'), file.content_type)})

# Delete file
 os.remove(file.filename)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone stuck with same problem, just convert to `BufferedReader`

like this:

```
    from io import BufferedReader
    image = request.files.get('name')
    image.name = image.filename
    image = BufferedReader(image)
```

and then you can post it

```
    requests.post(urlToUnknownServer,files={'file' : image})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try without file() constructor:

```
obj = request.files['fileName'].read().encode('string-escape')
requests.post(urlToUnknownServer,files={'file':obj})
```